# IP fragmentation and TCP header

Tags: tcp, ip, ip-fragmentation

I've read in [Firewalls for Dummies, 2nd edition book, page 58](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YlVJO.jpg), that for performance purposes, TCP header is attached only to the first IP fragment while the rest of the fragment carry only the application payload. Is that true?

UPDATE : Reference added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not 'for performance purposes'. It wouldn't make sense. IP fragments only need to contain IP headers. The payload, whatever it is, doesn't need to be repeated.

Comment: I understand that IP fragmentation process considers TCP header like any plain data payload ?

Comment: Correct, it neither knows nor cares.